# Postgres JSON array contains given array element

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

I have been searching for this answer for long on stackoverflow, but did not find anything useful.
I have data in my_tbl as:

```
folder_id |  links                                                                                                     
--------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
   761 | [{"ids": "[82293,82292]", "index": "index_1"}, {"ids": "[82293,82292]", "index": "index_2"}]
   769 | [{"ids": "[82323,82324]", "index": "index_3"}]
   572 | [{"ids": "[80031,79674,78971]", "index": "index_4"}]
   785 | [{"ids": "[82367,82369]", "index": "index_5"}, {"ids": "[82368,82371]", "index": "index_6"}]
   768 | [{"ids": "[82292,82306]", "index": "index_7"}]
```

I want to get all the rows where links->>'ids' contain 82292. So in this case, it should return me folder_id 761 and 768.

I achieved so far is separating ids arrays from links by - 
jsonb_array_elements(links) ->> 'ids'

not sure how to proceed further.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use `jsonb_array_elements` to convert a json array to a rowset.  You can use this to at the value of "ids".  Using [the `@>` operator](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-json.html) you can check if the array contains a value:

```
select  distinct folder_id
from    YourTable
cross join lateral
        jsonb_array_elements(links) ids(ele)      
where   (ele->>'ids')::jsonb @> '[82292]'
```

A tricky part is that `"[82293,82292]"` is stored as a string, not an array.  The `ele->>'ids'` expression retrieves `"[82293,82292]"` as string using the `->>` operator (the double `>` makes it return text instead of `jsonb`.)  The content of the string is converted to an array by `::jsonb`.

[Example at rextester.com.](http://rextester.com/CTGVI25902)

Comment: Also, something I tried to get more out of the query -> search array of elements;  something like, ele.id IN ('82292', '82324') that works too.

Comment: Looks like you can do that with `@>`, check if the left-hand side array contains the right-hand side array

Comment: Really like the use of the `cross join lateral` - nice solution.

Comment: Hi Andomar. This solution is really helpful. If you are trying to check if links has multiple ids, then this seems to work in Postgres 11.10.

`where  (ele->>'ids')::jsonb @> '[82292]' AND (ele->>'ids')::jsonb @> '[82306]'`

However, on my machine with Postgres 12.3 this results in 0 rows returned. Do you know why this may not be working on a later version?